# How do you stop the Blinking in Python Turtle when you change text every iteration in a loop?

Tags: python, python-turtle, flicker

During Runtime, The Canvas Blinks as it changes

It's supposed to change the co-ordinates every iteration but it blinks for some reason

```py
import turtle, time
turtle.setup()
turtle.screensize(200000,200000,'white')
t=turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(False)
t.up()
t.goto(0,0)
t.down()
t.goto(100000,0)
t.up()
t.goto(0,0)
t.down()
t.goto(0,100000)
t.up()
t.goto(0,0)
t.down()
i=0
turtle.tracer(True)
tt=turtle.Turtle()
tt.up()
screen = turtle.Screen()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
for line in open("tFile.txt","r"):
    i+=1
    t.goto(i,int(line))
    tt.goto(i,int(line))
    tt.write("( "+str(i)+" , "+line+" )")
    time.sleep(.01)
    t.getscreen().getcanvas().xview_moveto(0.5+(i/200000)-(300/200000))
    t.getscreen().getcanvas().yview_moveto(0.5-(int(line)/200000)-(300/200000))
    tt.clear()
turtle.done()
```